# Add an active class at the same time as toggle?

Tags: css, toggle

I have the following that slides a panel up fine however, i need an active class adding to footer--button at the same time, i’ve tried the below as two separate functions but no luck.

The active one on its own works fine, just not together. I’m not sure what i’m doing wrong...

```
$(".footer--button a.control").click(function () {
   $("footer.hidden").slideToggle("fast");
 });

$('.footer--button a.control').on('click', function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
   });
```

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the class on `footer--button` then you can use `closest()` like this:

```
$(".footer--button a.control").click(function () {
   $("footer.hidden").slideToggle("fast");
   $(this).closest('.footer--button').toggleClass('active');
});
```

*Note this can change based on your HTML*

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, i also figured out another way..

```
    $(".footer--button a.control").click(function () {
    $("footer.hidden").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
 });
```

Which adds it to the a.control link.

I’ll probably use yours though.